# getting NoMethodError Undefined method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

getting `NoMethodError Undefined method service_account_id` under valid_restriction? method.
Can anybody check why am I getting this error?

If you have links to resolve this, that would be helpful too. Thanks.
Error:
ERROR:

<NoMethodError: undefined method `service_account_id' for #String:0x0000560784713130>

authentication_request.rb:19:in `valid_restriction?'

Code Snippet below:

```
module Authentication
  module AuthnGcp

    class DecodedToken

      PROJECT_ID_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME = "google/compute_engine/project_id"
      INSTANCE_NAME_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME = "google/compute_engine/instance_name"
      SUB_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME = "sub"
      EMAIL_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME = "email"
      AUDIENCE_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME = "aud"

      attr_reader :project_id, :instance_name, :service_account_id, :service_account_email, :audience

      def initialize(decoded_token_hash:, logger:)
        @decoded_token_hash = decoded_token_hash
        @logger = logger

        initialize_required_claims
        initialize_optional_claims
      end

      private

      def initialize_required_claims
        @audience = required_token_claim_value(AUDIENCE_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME)
        @service_account_id = required_token_claim_value(SUB_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME)
      end

      def initialize_optional_claims
        @service_account_email = optional_token_claim_value(EMAIL_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME)
        @project_id = optional_token_claim_value(PROJECT_ID_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME)
        @instance_name = optional_token_claim_value(INSTANCE_NAME_TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME)
      end

      def required_token_claim_value(required_token_claim)
        required_token_claim_value = token_claim_value(required_token_claim)

        if required_token_claim_value.nil? || required_token_claim_value.empty?
          raise Errors::Authentication::Jwt::TokenClaimNotFoundOrEmpty, required_token_claim
        end

        log_claim_extracted_from_token(required_token_claim, required_token_claim_value)

        required_token_claim_value
      end

      def optional_token_claim_value(optional_token_claim)
        optional_token_claim_value = token_claim_value(optional_token_claim)

        if optional_token_claim_value.nil? || optional_token_claim_value.empty?
          optional_token_claim_value = nil
          @logger.debug(LogMessages::Authentication::Jwt::OptionalTokenClaimNotFoundOrEmpty.new(optional_token_claim))
        else
          log_claim_extracted_from_token(optional_token_claim, optional_token_claim_value)
        end

        optional_token_claim_value
      end

      def token_claim_value(token_claim)
        token_claim_path = token_claim.split('/')
        @decoded_token_hash.dig(*token_claim_path)
      end

      def log_claim_extracted_from_token(token_claim, token_claim_value)
        @logger.debug(
          LogMessages::Authentication::Jwt::ExtractedClaimFromToken.new(
            token_claim,
            token_claim_value
          )
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

==========================================================================

```
module Authentication
  module AuthnGcp

    # This class is responsible for retrieving the correct value from the GCP token
    # of the requested attribute.
    class AuthenticationRequest
      def initialize(decoded_token:)
        @decoded_token = decoded_token
      end

      def valid_restriction?(restriction)
        token_value =
          case restriction.name
          when Restrictions::PROJECT_ID
            @decoded_token.project_id
          when Restrictions::INSTANCE_NAME
            @decoded_token.instance_name
          when Restrictions::SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID
            @decoded_token.service_account_id
          when Restrictions::SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
            @decoded_token.service_account_email
          end

        raise Errors::Authentication::AuthnGcp::JwtTokenClaimIsMissing, restriction.name if token_value.blank?

        token_value == restriction.value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show the full error, not just a snippet of it. This could be `nil`, or it could be that no such method exists on the thing as you think it does.

Comment: @tadman ERROR:

<NoMethodError: undefined method `service_account_id' for #<String:0x0000560784713130>>

authentication_request.rb:19:in `valid_restriction?'

Comment: If that token is a `String` then you're not going to be able to call arbitrary methods on it, are you? Are you sure that's the correct type? Maybe your "decoded token" isn't actually decoded.

Comment: @tadman That decoded token is meant to be basically a GCP identity token(jwt payload)..

Comment: Does not appear to be the case. Are you sure you decoded it? Are you sure you assigned the decoded result into that variable before passing it along?